# Как сделать рендер компонента раз в секунду?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Столкнулся с проблемой что у меня приходит изменение около 30 раз на секунду. Следовательно компоненты куда передаются эти данные постоянно ренднряться.  Пробовал использовать throttle но проблема в том что я писал кастомный хук useThrottle и использовался он только для какой-нибудь функции. Возможно ли сделать для всего компонента,  то есть неважно приходят ли данные или нет рендерить компонент каждую секунду?

Comment: Что-то не так, если так часто обновляется.

Comment: Можно завести счетчик через `useState` и обновлять его каждую секунду (`setInterval` поставить в `useEffect`). Это позволит вызывать обновление каждую секунду, но не убережет от обновлений приходящих через props/state. Чтобы сделать точно раз в секунду, то надо использовать классовый компонент с методамм `shouldComponentUpdate` и `forceUpdate`.